# Human mass to energy equivalence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, mass-energy

This [article](https://www.universetoday.com/114617/a-fun-way-of-understanding-emc2/) states that the average human has a mass energy equivalence of 7.8 septillion joules of energy

Converting this into a temperature using $E=k_B T$, we have a temperature on the order of $10^{41} K$, which is obviously not the case.

- I’m obviously being dumb, but what am I missing?
- This is an awful lot of energy, is it usable?

Comment: Can you explain why you think relativistic rest energy contributes to temperature?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Using $E=k_B T$?

Comment: That's just an equation. Why do you think $E$ in that equation is the same $E$ in $E=mc^2$?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I have nothing to make me think otherwise. I’ve informally been told that mass and energy are equivalent and seen my particle physics lecturer convert between energy and temperature. I know I’m obviously misunderstanding something, but not sure what, hence the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your use of the Boltzmann constant in this fashion implicitly assumes that all of the energy in the system (human) is contained in a single internal degree of freedom.

The concept of thermal energy assumes that a system has a large number of internal degrees of freedom. In an ideal monoatomic gas under typical conditions this is limited to the KE of the gas atoms, but it is important to understand that in general **thermal energy is not only due to kinetic energy of the molecules** but includes all internal degrees of freedom. The idea that thermal energy is internal kinetic energy is a mistaken over-generalization from the case of an ideal gas.

In other materials the thermal energy is also found in other internal degrees of freedom, such as rotational and vibrational modes, excited electron orbital modes, and at high enough temperatures particle modes. The equipartition theorem says that thermal energy is evenly distributed throughout these internal degrees of freedom.

The Boltzmann constant converts between temperature and the amount of energy in each of these internal degrees of freedom. Due to quantum mechanics, these modes have a minimum energy required to excite it above the ground state. If the energy per degree of freedom is less than this minimum energy then the degree of freedom is said to be “frozen out” and does not participate in the thermal exchange. In particular, at human body temperature the particle modes are well frozen out. This means that the mass energy of the particles in the body does not participate in thermal exchange.

At the large temperature you calculated each degree of freedom (e.g. the KE of a single particle) would possess enough energy to produce a human!  At our lower temperature most of our energy is in frozen out degrees of freedom. Very little of our mass energy is therefore available to contribute to thermal exchange.

Comment: Technically, $E=k_BT$ assumes *two* such DOFs (if their contribution to the KE is quadratic).

Comment: @J.G. You are absolutely correct, I glossed over the missing factor of 1/2. I cannot see a way to include it that doesn’t distract from the main message

Comment: Wouldn't rotation and vibration also count as kinetic energy, since they are forms of movement? I guess it's just a matter of terminology

Comment: -1 from me. You didn't say that the energy is from $mc^2$ rather than temperature.

Comment: @gardenhead rotation would, but not vibration. Vibration involves both KE and PE. Similarly with any bending or torsion modes.

Comment: @MaxW vote how you will but 1) temperature is not a form of energy, the right term is “thermal energy” 2) by $E=mc^2$ the thermal energy also contributes to the mass so it would make no sense at all to say that “the energy is from $mc^2$ rather than thermal energy”

Comment: @Dale - You get that the only way to get that much energy is to convert the total mass of the human to energy. In other words, the human blows up like an atom bomb. Via Einstein's equation $E=mc^2$

Comment: @MaxW you have a mistaken understanding of $E=mc^2$, one that is unfortunately very common. There is no need to “convert” mass to energy. As you sit there you already have ~8 septillion J, even while fully intact and not blown up. $E=mc^2$ means that energy *always* has mass and mass *always* has energy. Mass energy can be converted to other forms of energy, but mass energy is itself a perfectly valid form of energy. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461534/thermal-energy-turning-into-mass?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Dale - I assure you that I have no mistaken understanding. I understand the mass energy equivalency. So if I have 1 kg of mass. I would say that the mass can be converted to  joules of heat. What verb would you like me to use instead of "converted"?

Comment: @Dale Thanks, I forgot about that. Does the KE and PE of a vibration count as one or two degrees of freedom?

Comment: @gardenhead it would depend on the molecule how many degrees of freedom but if it is vibrating in one mode (eg aa molecule of two identical atoms stretching closer and further) then it is one degree of freedom where the energy in that one degree of freedom sloshes back and forth between KE and PE

Answer (score 7):

Temperature as we know it is ***mostly*** due to the **kinetic energy** of the atoms of any object (the rotational and vibrational energy of the atoms also accounts in the temperature). Now the energy in $E = mc^2$ is not kinetic energy, rather it is the energy stored by the mass of the object itself. So, while the 'mas energy' of a human may be 7.8 septillion joules, that is not the kinetic energy that we perceive as temperature. And that's why we don't have a temperature of $10^{41}$ K.

Comment: this is wrong, you should read/study the answer below from @Dale

Comment: Yeah, thanks for noting, fixed it a bit, mentioned other DOFs.